# Run .Net 6 code on App Service Plan (Linux )

Tags: linux, azure, azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans

I am having Event Grid Trigger Azure Function(.Net 6 App) which is running on P2V2 plan (App Service) Windows OS. I am planning to run it on Linux OS in App Service hosting plan to save cost.

In Windows based App Service plan, I provide configuration settings in following way

```
[
  {
    "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
    "value": "",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "ApplicationInsights:LogLevel",
    "value": "Information",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",    
     "value":"",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "Component:ComponentId",
    "value": "",
    "slotSetting": false
  }
]
```

While deploying to Linux based OS, `ApplicationInsights:LogLevel` config setting doesn't accept because of colon(:) is not supported. What should I do in that case to run in Linux OS in App Service hosting plan ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Dependency injection configuration is setup in function class file by default.
- We need to add few configuration changes, Add `logLevel`  settings in `host.json` file.

***My host.json :***

```cs
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    },
    "logLevel": {
      "AzureFunction.Sample": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

- `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY`and  `AzureWebJobsStorage`  are added in the `local.settings.json` file
  as below

***My local.settings.json***

```cs
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "Copy the Instrumentation Key from Application Insights"
  },

  "Component": {
    "ComponentId": "",
    "value": "",
    "slotSetting": false
  }
}
```

Hosted the App in Azure Linux Hosting Plan.

***Application Insights Traces :***
[image]

Comment: - Did you know how can i check my deployed files in App Service Linux ?